# Git - creating a new branch and committing only to this one?

Tags: git, github

I've tried to research online and couldn't find any sources.

Basically I've got 2 parts to a coursework, part 1 was submitted recently and has all been version controlled on git (master branch).

For part 2, I'd like to create a new branch, add all my existing commits (and files) to this branch, and continue committing. I'm done with part 1 but I'd still like the code to see where I left off with, in a seperate branch.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: creating a branch at the head of master would already include all your existing commits, than your new commits would go on your 2nd branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new branch in git contains all of your files and history of your current commits. Running `git checkout -b [newBranchName]` will checkout your new branch with all of your current files and commits under its version control.

Comment: Okay. After checking out, do I just commit and push normally? I.e. `git commit -m "commit message"`, `git push origin master`? Is it still `master` I type?

Comment: Since you are on a new branch, you would type `git push origin [newBranchName]` instead since `master` is your original branch.

Comment: Okay, and if I decided I wanted to commit to my old (part1) branch, it would just be `git push origin master` as usual?

Comment: you could just use `git push`, that by default expands to `git push origin current_branch_name`, which by default means `git push origin current_local_branch_name:remote_branch_name`

Comment: @apprenticeDev If I type `git commit -m ...` would I just type `git push origin [branchName]` to choose which branch to push this commit to, or would I first need to do `git checkout [branchName]` before committing?

Comment: So, on your computer - you have a copy of the repository. When you do `git commit ...` - you commit locally, and it will write the commit to whichever branch you are on (running `git branch` will show you all local branches, with * in front of current branch). After you commit, you can push the branch to remote repository - with `git push remote_name branch_name`. So, to add something to "part 1" - locally do `git checkout master`, then do your work, then commit, then push. Get back to part 2 with `git checkout part_2`. Makes sense?